# How can I change google checkout currency from sandbox in google checkout seller account?

Tags: android-pay, google-checkout

My cart's currency is in AUD but my google checkout's currency is set to USD. Now I cannot execute a successful transaction in test mode where the request is being processed in sandbox. I tried several times to find out the currency setting in google checkout's merchant account but I failed. Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Google Checkout is available for US and UK merchants only. As a US or UK merchant you can sell to most international buyers, but the transaction currency must be the same as the currency of the account (either USD or GBP).

If you are selling digital goods consider the Wallet for digital goods API which is available to merchants in 18 countries (including Australia and AUD):

https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/faq#faq-gen-02

https://support.google.com/wallet/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48414